# Django: Using current user as a foreign key to projects model

Tags: python, django

I am building a web-app where people can write projects. The projects are stored in a model and I want to use the user as the foreign key so I can show the user their projects on a webpage. Instances are entered through a form.

The code always assigns the default value (1) and and not the user. Can any of you see what's causing this bug?

Here is the code for the creation of the model in models.py:

```
class PersonalProject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    code = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Heres the code for the form view to create the project in views.py:

```
def newproject(request):

    if User is None:
        messages.error(request, "Must be signed in")
        return redirect('main:dashboard')

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewProjectForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('main:dashboard')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Error")
    else:
        form = NewProjectForm()

    return render(request,
                "main/newproject.html",
                {"form":form})
```

Heres the code for the homepage view in views.py:

```
def dashboard(request):
    messages.info(request, request.user.username)
    return render(request=request,
                template_name="main/dashboard.html",
                context={"structuredprojects": StructuredProject.objects.all(), "personalprojects": PersonalProject.objects.filter(user__username=request.user.username)})
```

I really hope you can help - I've been stuck on this for a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the user of the instance wrapped in the form to `request.user`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def newproject(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewProjectForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('main:dashboard')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Error")
    else:
        form = NewProjectForm()

    return render(request,
                "main/newproject.html",
                {"form":form})
```

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
>   [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).